# How to create two custom tableview cell within single tableview using iOS Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create accordion tableview with seperate tableviewCell within single tableview using iOS storyboard. below I have added my test code. Please help me for solving issues.

My Source:

**Tableview Methods Index data's I am getting from property list**

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [self.itemsInTable count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *Title= [[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
        return [self createCellWithTitle:Title image:[[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Image name"] indexPath:indexPath];
    }

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSDictionary *dic=[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if([dic valueForKey:@"SubItems"])
        {
            NSArray *arr=[dic valueForKey:@"SubItems"];
            BOOL isTableExpanded=NO;

            for(NSDictionary *subitems in arr )
            {
                NSInteger index=[self.itemsInTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:subitems];
                isTableExpanded=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
                if(isTableExpanded) break;
            }

            if(isTableExpanded)
            {
                [self CollapseRows:arr];
            }
            else
            {
                NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
                NSMutableArray *arrCells=[NSMutableArray array];
                for(NSDictionary *dInner in arr )
                {
                    [arrCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                    [self.itemsInTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
                }
                [self.main_tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arrCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            }
        }
    }
```

CollapseRow Process

```
-(void)CollapseRows:(NSArray*)ar
{
    for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar )
    {
        NSUInteger indexToRemove=[self.itemsInTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
        NSArray *arInner=[dInner valueForKey:@"SubItems"];
        if(arInner && [arInner count]>0)
        {
            [self CollapseRows:arInner];
        }

        if([self.itemsInTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner]!=NSNotFound)
        {
            [self.itemsInTable removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            [self.main_tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:0]
                                                        ]
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        }
    }
}
```

**Tableview UI. Same UI appearing Into child tableview cell also. I need to show seperate UI for parent and child tableview cell**

```
- (UITableViewCell*)createCellWithTitle:(NSString *)title image:(UIImage *)image  indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier_one = @"Cell_One";

    cell_one = [self.main_tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier_one];

    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:54/255.0f green:169/255.0f blue:224/255.0f alpha:0.40f];
    cell_one.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:54/255.0f green:169/255.0f blue:224/255.0f alpha:0.25f];
    cell_one.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
    cell_one.titlelbl.text = title;
    cell_one.titlelbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return cell_one;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I've read this 4 times now and I still can't figure out what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I did. Please check It @Stonz2

Comment: Im afraid I don't get it either. All the code doesn't help btw

Comment: above code I have coded for single tableview cell replacing both parent and child. Now I need to create seperate custom cells Xib. how to Integrate seperate logic? @Daij-Djan

Comment: well you have indexPath. YOU must know which cell to use for which indexPath

Comment: @android did you want two tableview in single view controller ?

Comment: Please check above code. @Kishore Kumar

Answer (score 0):

well you have indexPath. YOU must know which cell to use for which indexPath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id cell;
    if(indexPath.row==0) {
        cell = [self createCell];
    }
    else {
        cell = [self createOtherCell];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please give me more details. My above code If SubItems available It will allow for child tableview cell. Now the plm is both cells showing same titles. !@Daij-Djan